# Deleting middle element out of a given list in ML

Tags: ml

I am brand new to learning standard ML. I want to make a function that takes a list/lists of 3 numbers and deletes the middle number and then reverse the order of the two numbers.   So if I have a input of (3, 4, 5) then I want to return (5, 3).

This is what I have so far:

fun twiddle []  = []
| twiddle (x::xs) = x::twiddle xs;

I am not sure how to distinguish the middle item of the list and then delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are always three numbers, use a pattern matching three elements:

```
fun twiddle [a,b,c] = [c,a]
```